# Get full item of a dropdown in a *ngFor

Tags: angular

I want to obtain the complete object of the element that I currently have selected in my dropdown. Currently I get the selected value and this is fine for me! but additional I want to obtain the complete object. How can I do it?

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="user" (change)="fn_consolidadoUsuario()"  mdbInput    > 
    <option *ngFor="let item of aUser" [value]="item.iduser">{{item.name}} 
    </option>
```

```
user:any
aUser:
[
{
    "iduser":1, "name":"joe"
},
{
    "iduser":1, "name":"berta"
},
{
    "iduser":1, "name":"francisco"
}
]


this.user=1; //value by default

fn_consolidadoUsuario(){
 console.log(this.user)// 1
 //also I need the actual item    {"iduser":1, "name":"joe"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `[ngValue]="item"` and `[compareWith]="compareData"` for this.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-full-item-of-a-dropdown-in-a-ngfor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**component.ts**

```
user:any={"iduser":2,"name":"berta"} 

aUser=[
    {"iduser":1, "name":"joe"},
    {"iduser":2, "name":"berta"},
    {"iduser":3, "name":"francisco"}
]

fn_consolidadoUsuario(){
    console.log(this.user)
}

compareData(a, b) {
    return a && b && a.iduser == b.iduser;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="user" (change)="fn_consolidadoUsuario()"  mdbInput  [compareWith]="compareData"  > 
    <option *ngFor="let item of aUser" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}} 
    </option>
</select>

<pre>{{user | json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do

```
fn_consolidadoUsuario(){
  const mySelectedUser = this.aUser.find(cursor => cursor.iduser === this.user);
}
```

Comment: This may solve OP's problem, but it would be more helpful if it also explained *why* it solves OP's problem. Code that works is much less helpful than code that works **and** you understand :)